# Standard way to handle circular references in beforeSave or beforeDelete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, parse-platform

Say in my parse.com data I have a Family class and the families have an array of children who are members of the the Child class.  Say also that the Child has a back pointer to its Family, and that the Family caches some data about it's children, like the name of the eldest child.

I'd like to maintain integrity for as much of this as possible using beforeSave and beforeDelete.  So for example, beforeDeleting a child I'd like to remove that child from its family, and I might need to update the family's eldest child.  That's fine, but I also want to, before deleting a family, delete that family's children.

Therein lies my concern:  If, when deleting a family, I delete all the children, and if, when deleting each child, I need to manipulate that child's family, saving it repeatedly, will I fail because I'm trying to update while deleting?

Is there some standard rule I can apply for what I can and cannot do in beforeSave/beforeDelete hooks?

I have this problem in parse.com, **but I can see how the same problem might occur in a rails project**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue that concerns single responsibility principle.  If you delete a child and you want to update the family's eldest after that, the child object shouldn't know that you're updating so what you probably want to do is use a service class when deleting a child.

On the other hand, when you delete a family, just set the `dependent` option to `:destroy`.

As you can see, you can always *do anything* in the service class after deleting a child without worrying about any callbacks that will affect other models, because, ideally, the child model shouldn't be updating other models when it is created/updated/deleted.

A sample service class will look like

```
class ChildDeleter
  def initialize(child)
    @child = child
  end

  def process_destroy
    child.destroy
    update_eldest
  end

  private

  attr_reader :child

  def update_eldest
    # add code here to update the eldest member of the family
  end
end

# in your controller
def destroy
  child = Child.find(params[:id])
  ChildDeleter.new(child).process_destroy
end
```

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense.  Maybe I'd generalize by saying: use delete/save hooks to change objects you point to, and use app logic to change objects that point to you.